# function return type is vector in c++

Tags: c++, function, vector

i want vector as return type of function in my code like,

```
class SocketTransportClient{
    void sendData(RMLInfoset *info){
        vector<unsigned long>::iterator blockIterator;
        vector<unsigned long> vectBlock=info->getRML(); // error :  error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::vector<_Ty>' to 'std::vector<_Ty>'
    }
}

class RMLInfoset  {
    vector<unsigned int> RMLInfoset::getRML(){
        return  vectDataBlock;
    }
}
```

but it show an error  'cannot convert from 'std::vector<_Ty>' to 'std::vector<_Ty>' '
so please any one help me,
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Well, part of the problem is that you never actually build the `vector v` in `Myfun`.

```
std::vector<int> Myfun() {
  std::vector<int> v;
  return v;
}
```

EDIT:

After the question edit, there is still a small problem - you need to declare the vector as a `std::vector<int>`, not just a `vector<int>`, as above.  This is because vector resides in the `std` namespace.

Comment: After your last edit, I would post an answer, but Greg Hewgill has already been nice enough to do so.  Read his answer. :)

Answer (score 5):

Your function is declared to return `vector<unsigned int>` but you're *actually* trying to assign the result to a `vector<unsigned long>`. Those are different types and not assignment-compatible. Change your function declaration:

```
  vector<unsigned long> RMLInfoset::getRML(){
```

You will also need to change the type of `vectDataBlock`. Basically, decide which vector type you want to use and *be consistent*.

Answer (score 2):

You have three errors

1) You didn't use `#include <vector>`

2) It should be `std::vector<int> v;` instead of `vector<int> v;`

3) You didn't post all of your code.